# Polygon to line (polyline) in R

Tags: r, polygon, line

I am looking for an easy way to convert a polygon to a polyline in r. 
I have tried this but dit not succeed:

```
polygon <- readOGR("~path/", "polygon.shp")
polyline <- as(polygon, "SpatialLinesDataFrame")
writeOGR(polyline, dsn="~path/", layer="polyline.shp", driver="ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me.

Here's a shapefile, I inspect it at the command line and see its got "(Polygon)" geometry:

```
$ ogrinfo -so Great_Lakes.shp
INFO: Open of `Great_Lakes.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
1: Great_Lakes (Polygon)
```

Now read into R:

```
> library(rgdal)
> lakes = readOGR(".","Great_Lakes")
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: "/nobackup/rowlings/Downloads/SO/lakes/Convert", layer: "Great_Lakes"
with 1 features
It has 4 fields
Integer64 fields read as strings:  OBJECTID dissolve
```

Convert as you do:

```
> plakes = as(lakes, "SpatialLinesDataFrame")
```

and save:

```
> writeOGR(plakes, dsn=".",layer="Great_Lakes", driver="ESRI Shapefile",overwrite_layer=TRUE)
>
```

Now back in the command line I inspect, and its "(Line String)" geometry.

```
$ ogrinfo -so Great_Lakes.shp
INFO: Open of `Great_Lakes.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
1: Great_Lakes (Line String)
```

So unless by "poly line" you mean something other than a list of lines, I think you are doing it.

Comment: Polyline are not overlapped lines. This code work great but the lines next to each other are repeated. I'm trying to estimate total length of borders in a layer, but with this approach the value is overestimated ...

Comment: @gonzalez.ivan90 that's a different problem, and will require some sort of merge/union of features first. Make a new question with maybe some sample data and it might get answered. Might also be worth doing with `sf` spatial objects instead of `sp` as here.